# Columns of grouped checked boxes overlapping with one another

Tags: qml

So, I'm trying to create a filter box for an ecommerce-based application that I'm working on and I want to make multiple button groups of check boxes within columns. I tried to separate the different columns but they overlap with one another. For example, the priceColumn overlaps with the conditionColumn. I am looking for a way to separate each button group by line. Is there anyway around this or any other solution that you would suggest? I'm new to QML by the way.

Here's my code for example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

import "." as NeroshopComponents

Pane {
    id: filterBox
    clip: true // The area in which the contents of the filterBox will be bounded to (set width and height) // If clip is false then the contents will go beyond/outside of the filterBox's bounds
    width: 250; height: 540
    background: Rectangle { 
        color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#2e2e2e"/*"#121212"*/ : "#a0a0a0"
        radius: 3
    }    
    // conditionGroup
    ButtonGroup {
        id: conditionButtonGroup
        buttons: conditionColumn.children
        exclusive: false // more than one button in the group can be checked at any given time
        checkState: conditionParentBox.checkState
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Selected condition:", button.text)
            if(checkState == Qt.Unchecked) {
                console.log("checkState: NO button is checked")
            }
            if(checkState == Qt.Checked) {
                console.log("checkState: All buttons are checked")
            }            
            if(checkState == Qt.PartiallyChecked) {
                console.log("checkState: One or more buttons are checked")
            }
        }
    }
    // priceGroup
    ButtonGroup {
        id: priceButtonGroup
        buttons: priceColumn.children
        exclusive: false // more than one button in the group can be checked at any given time
        checkState: priceParentBox.checkState
        onClicked: {
            console.log("Selected price range:", button.text)
            if(checkState == Qt.Unchecked) {
                console.log("checkState: NO button is checked")
            }
            if(checkState == Qt.Checked) {
                console.log("checkState: All buttons are checked")
            }            
            if(checkState == Qt.PartiallyChecked) {
                console.log("checkState: One or more buttons are checked")
            }
        }
    }        
    ////////////////////
    Rectangle {
        id: filterOptions
        //anchors.fill: parent
            x: -horizontalScrollBar.position * width
            y: -verticalScrollBar.position * height        
            color: "transparent"
            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
        Column {//ColumnLayout {
            id: conditionColumn
            
            Text { 
                text: qsTr("Condition"); 
                font.bold: true
                color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
            }
            CheckBox {
                id: conditionParentBox
                //text: qsTr("Any")//qsTr("Parent")
                checkState: conditionButtonGroup.checkState
                
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Any")
                    color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    anchors.left: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: (parent.height - this.contentHeight) / 2
                }                
            }        
            CheckBox { 
                //checked: false
                //text: qsTr("New")
                leftPadding: indicator.width
                ButtonGroup.group: conditionButtonGroup
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("New")
                    color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    anchors.left: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: (parent.height - this.contentHeight) / 2
                }                      
            }
            CheckBox { 
                //text: qsTr("Used")
                leftPadding: indicator.width
                ButtonGroup.group: conditionButtonGroup
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Used")
                    color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    anchors.left: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: (parent.height - this.contentHeight) / 2
                }                      
            }
            CheckBox { 
                //text: qsTr("Refurbished/Renewed")
                leftPadding: indicator.width
                ButtonGroup.group: conditionButtonGroup
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Refurbished/Renewed")
                    color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    anchors.left: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: (parent.height - this.contentHeight) / 2
                }                      
            }
        }
        ////////////////////////
        Column {//ColumnLayout {
            id: priceColumn
            Text { 
                text: qsTr("Price")
                font.bold: true
                color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
            }
            CheckBox { 
                id: priceParentBox
                checkState: priceButtonGroup.checkState
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("Any")
                    color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    anchors.left: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: (parent.height - this.contentHeight) / 2
                }                
            }
            CheckBox { 
                leftPadding: indicator.width
                ButtonGroup.group: priceButtonGroup       
                Text {
                    text: qsTr("$0.00-$1.00")
                    color: (NeroshopComponents.Style.darkTheme) ? "#ffffff" : "#000000"
                    anchors.left: parent.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 0
                    anchors.top: parent.top
                    anchors.topMargin: (parent.height - this.contentHeight) / 2
                }                       
            }
        }        
        } // Rectangle: filterOptions
        ScrollBar {
            id: verticalScrollBar
            hoverEnabled: true
            active: hovered || pressed
            orientation: Qt.Vertical
            size: (filterBox.height - 20) / filterOptions.height//filterBox.background.height / conditionColumn.height // 20 is the bottomMargin I guess?
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }

        ScrollBar {
            id: horizontalScrollBar
            hoverEnabled: true
            active: hovered || pressed
            orientation: Qt.Horizontal
            size: filterBox.background.width / filterOptions.width
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            policy: ScrollBar.AsNeeded
        }
        // todo: sort by category, price, ratings, brand, color, etc.
}
```

Comment: Use [Layouts](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-layouts-layout.html) instead. Never use absolute positioning,

Comment: Just curious, but is absolute positioning really that bad? And what are the main benefits of a Layout?

Comment: In this case, I think the main advantage is the ability to avoid such situations. Also flexibility, convenience and the declarative approach.

Comment: I agree with @folibis. We have used Qt for some time now and learning to use Layouts for positioning means less concern about absolute pixels and allows you to scale your app for multiple devices, multiple resolutions, device pixel ratios (retina displays), orientations and so forth. When you use absolute numbers, you're in a whole world of hurt where you have to do math to achieve pixel perfection and it distracts you from the business of your application. Layouts are less intuitive, initially, but, once you master it, it is worth it in the long run.

Comment: As an aside, Checkboxes already contain a `text` property. Why do you add your own `Text` object inside each one?

Comment: The priceColumn overlaps the conditionColumn because there's no position given (either through layouts, anchors or x/y) for either of them. By default they'll both just be drawn in the top left corner of their parent Rectangle.

Comment: @JarMan I wanted to change the check box text color which is why I added my own Text object inside each one.

And thanks for answering my question. I will try to change the position using layouts/anchors.

Comment: @Stephen Quan Thank you for the highly detailed information on Layouts. It really helped me understand Layouts better. I'll start using Layouts more often from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced your anchoring with `ColumnLayout`. I replaced `Rectangle` for `Frame` has an automatic border and padding effect. I replaced `CheckBox` for `RadioButton`, since, for exclusivity per group since your UI implied that use case. Qt QML automatically figures out how to deal with the two `RadioButton` groups since they fall in their own `Frame`/`ColumnLayout` so we needn't explicitly define a `ButtonGroup`. I replaced your `ScrollBar` implementation with `ScrollBar.vertical`

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    Flickable {
        id: flickable
        anchors.fill: parent
        contentWidth: columnLayout.width
        contentHeight: columnLayout.height
        clip: true
        ColumnLayout {
            id: columnLayout
            width: flickable.width - 20
            Frame {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                ColumnLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    Label { text: qsTr("Condition") }
                    RadioButton { id: cond1; text: qsTr("Any") }
                    RadioButton { id: cond2; text: qsTr("New") }
                    RadioButton { id: cond3; text: qsTr("Used") }
                    RadioButton { id: cond4; text: qsTr("Refurbished/Renew") }
                    Text {
                        text:      (cond1.checked && cond1.text)
                                || (cond2.checked && cond2.text)
                                || (cond3.checked && cond3.text)
                                || (cond4.checked && cond4.text)
                                || qsTr("Nothing Selected")
                    }
                }
            }
            Frame {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                ColumnLayout {
                    width: parent.width
                    Label { text: qsTr("Price") }
                    RadioButton { id: price1; text: qsTr("Any") }
                    RadioButton { id: price2; text: qsTr("$0.00-$1.00") }
                    Text {
                        text:      (price1.checked && price1.text)
                                || (price2.checked && price2.text)
                                || qsTr("Nothing Selected")
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}
```

[image: animate-gif]